# How to align a label and button at baseline?

Tags: layout, javafx

Id like to place a label and a button (and a text field) in a horizontal layout. This works, but the baselines are unaligned. How to fix that?

[image: Baselines are unaligned]

The expected result is that the red lines (baselines of each control) are at the same height.

This is the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <TextField text="Lorem Ipsum" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an alignment attribute to the `HBox` with value `"BASELINE_LEFT"`:

```
<HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <TextField text="Lorem Ipsum" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

[image]